# Python Selenium not change Scroll Height google maps reviews

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I am scrolling google maps reviews till end of scroll but I can't come outside of while loop. I am trying to scroll last height and new height after scrolling but it gives same.

output same height

```
2194
2194
2194
```

```
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
            print(last_height)
            while True:
                scroller = driver.find_element_by_class_name('review-dialog-list')
                driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight',scroller)
                sleep(3)
                new_height= driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
                #new_height = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset;")
                print(new_height)
```

Comment: share the exact link of  google maps

Answer (score 0):

> Finally I make a solution for this problem.

```
                while True:
                driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName(\'review-dialog-list\')[0].scrollTo(0, document.getElementsByClassName(\'review-dialog-list\')[0].scrollHeight)")
                sleep(5)
                new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName(\'review-dialog-list\')[0].scrollHeight")
                #print('new_height:', new_height)
                if new_height == last_height:
                    break
                else:
                    last_height = new_height
```